# Button action not thrown

Tags: ios

I am creating an iOS app. On a view controller there are several buttons.

One of them is the AButton, here you have my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)Aaction:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *AButton;

@end
```

I want to open another view controller when AButton is tapped:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "EntradasTableViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)Aaction:(id)sender {

    EntradasTableViewController *detailViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"entradasViewController"];
    detailViewController.categoriaDescription = @"A";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];


}
@end
```

I have declared the StoryBoard identifier as follows:

[image]

But after tapping on the button nothing happens, no exception is thrown and the view controller detailViewController is not shown.

Any help is welcome.

NEW IMAGED ADDED:

Here is a screenshot where I am declaring the action for the button in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Where is the button? And where is the action in the storyboard that would cause the button to _do_ anything?

Comment: @matt, the button is on a view controller called FirstViewController, I have put the header and implementation files for that view controller in my question. What do you mean when you ask for the action in the storyboard? You mean a segue?

Comment: @matt, I have updated my question to include a screenshot from the storyboard where I am declaring the action for the button.

Comment: put NSLog into the `Aaction:` method and see if it being called at all. If it is, then use more NSLog to see if `detailViewController` or `self.navigationController` is nil.

Comment: Thank you matt, I have logged both and the result is that self.navigationController is (null), detailViewController = EntradasTableViewController

Comment: Well, there you are. `self.navigationController` is nil, so `[self.navigationController pushViewController:...]` is a message to nil, so nothing happens. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your FirstViewController instance is not in a navigation interface. Therefore when your FirstViewController says `self.navigationController`, that's nil. Therefore this line:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

...involves sending a message to nil. In Objective-C, sending a message to nil does nothing. So that's why nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you, but how should I call detailViewController from FirstViewController inside the AAction method?

Comment: You can't call `pushViewController` at all if you're not in a navigation interface. If you were expecting to be in a navigation interface, you need to figure out why you're not and fix it so you are. If you were _not_ expecting to be in a navigation interface, you had no business using `pushViewController` anyway.

Comment: Thank you matt, I have solved it as follows:  EntradasTableViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"entradasViewController"];
    svc.categoriaDescription = @"A";
    [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Excellent! So you are using a _presented_ view controller instead of a _pushed_ view controller. And, to remove it, you will now _dismiss_ it instead of _popping_ it.